# Отключить V-on click для дочернего элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

У меня есть карточки с юзерами, мне нужно при нажатии на карточку получать его Id. Но событие @click срабатывает и на дочернии элементы (фото, имя, компания) и на пробелы между ними тоесть может вернуть любой дочерний элемент. Есть ли возможность отключить срабатывания для дочерних элементов и по клику в любом месте карточки получать в target именно её? Возможно есть какое то элегантное решение?+

Comment: Единственное что я придумал это повесить обработчик клика на дочерние элементы и брать у них El.parentNode, но тогда при клике на свободное место в карточке срабатывания не будет

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У дочерних элементов выставить CSS: pointer-events: none;